# Alternative to connectify

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualization

I've been using connectify for a while to share internate with flatmates (broken router) but it's rubbish. After working 1 night it was using 500MB of memory and 50% of CPU. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 7):

**[VirtualRouter.](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)**

> Virtual Router turns any Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2 Computer into a Wifi Hot Spot using Windows 7's Wireless Hosted Network (Virtual Wifi) technology.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for Data Cards.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an ad hoc wireless network ([XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx)) ([Vista/7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network)) using built-in Windows capabilities if the host computer is wired, but having never seriously used one I don't know what the performance is like.

Comment: Not good for connecting iPhone/Android devices which do not support ad-hoc networks... :(